# cargar dropzone dentro de un div (dinámico) que pasa por ajax

Tags: php, ajax, div, dropzone

Hola amigos estoy tratando de incorporar dropzone que viene de un archivo externo que pasa por ajax, pero no me funciona :/, si lo pongo en la página principal fuera de la sección dinámica (que utilizo para cargar contenido por ajax) funciona perfecto.

---

```html
<section class="page-section " id="areas"> Aquí es donde cargo mi contenido dinámico</section>
```

---

este es el código que viene en mi archivo externo

mediante un botón muestro una tabla con contenido y dentro de la tabla viene el formulario
no tengo idea de como realizar la selección dentro del contenido que viene por ajax.

```html
echo'<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Código</th>
      <th scope="col">Evidencia</th>
      <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
      <th scope="col">Archivo</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>'; 

if($resultEvidencias){                
     while ($evidencia = $resultEvidencias->fetch_array()){ 
     echo'<tr>
      <td>'.$evidencia['codigoEvidencia'].'</td>
      <td>'.$evidencia['nombreEvidencia'].'</td>
      <td>'.$evidencia['tipoEvidencia'].'</td>
      <td>';
      if(empty($evidencia['archivoEvidencia'])){

        echo'<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzonewidget"></form>';

       }else{
         echo $evidencia['archivoEvidencia'];                           
        }                       
      echo '</td></tr>';                                
  }

echo'</tbody></table>';
```

[![dropzone][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oT2d.png

muchas gracias por su apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses arquitectura por capas (Modelo, Vista, Controlador o similar) en lugar de lanzar los echo para pintar tu página. Es decir, usar archivos separados para tu vista en HTML, javascript, css y tu código en PHP para que tengas desacoplado el backend del frontend. Ésta práctica te permitirá tener un mejor control en lo que pasa en tu código.

Dicho esto, lo que puedes hacer es tener un archivo HTML (junto con su(s) CSS y .js) con todo lo que requieras y que no depende para nada del back y en tu archivo .php usar el comando [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) ([ejemplo](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=580:post-php-procesar-datos-de-un-formulario-html-ejercicios-resueltos-y-ejemplos-sencillos-cu00834b&catid=70&Itemid=193)) para obtener todo lo que tu front envíe al back.